# Java Conditions with Locks

Tags: java, multithreading, blocking, locks

Java docs from here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html

I am trying to understand the Conditions concept. In the below code, put and take both wait on the same Lock. The doc says that before calling any condition.await() we need to get hold of the corresponding lock `(here line 2 : final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();).`

My question is, lets say the buffer is full. In this case if we try to insert an object, the thread will be blocked till `count == items.length` but the lock here still remains with the thread which is trying to put. How can we call method take() to decrease the count, since take() needs to acquire the hold of the same Lock. It apears to me that this will be deadlock as take() cannot be called, same if the items is empty we won't be able to call put() since now the lock is already with take().

Kindly help me understand if i am missing anything.Thanks in advance.

```
class BoundedBuffer {
       final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
       final Condition notFull  = lock.newCondition(); 
       final Condition notEmpty = lock.newCondition(); 
    
       final Object[] items = new Object[100];
       int putptr, takeptr, count;
    
       public void put(Object x) throws InterruptedException {
         lock.lock();
         try {
           while (count == items.length)
             notFull.await();
           items[putptr] = x;
           if (++putptr == items.length) putptr = 0;
           ++count;
           notEmpty.signal();
         } finally {
           lock.unlock();
         }
       }
    
       public Object take() throws InterruptedException {
         lock.lock();
         try {
           while (count == 0)
             notEmpty.await();
           Object x = items[takeptr];
           if (++takeptr == items.length) takeptr = 0;
           --count;
           notFull.signal();
           return x;
         } finally {
           lock.unlock();
         }
       }
     }
```

Comment: [await()-javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#await()): "The lock associated with this Condition is atomically released and the current thread becomes disabled for thread scheduling purposes and lies dormant until one of four things happens:...", please also the "fine print" ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the api doc for Condition#await ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) it says:

> The lock associated with this Condition is atomically released and the current thread becomes disabled for thread scheduling purposes and lies dormant until one of four things happens:

Since the lock is released there is no problem with put acquiring the lock.

Comment: so is it similar to calling wait() on any object. I mean instead of the lock we can have synchronized over an object say obj and then wait on that obj.wait()

Comment: @cjava: yes it’s the same idea, except that being able to have different conditions for one lock is a big advantage. And synchronized uses a lock too, it’s the implicit lock on the object.

Comment: I guess using countdownlatch will be better here because calling signal will not completly ensure that the blocked thread is awakened. what is your advise

Comment: @cjava: calling signal means that a thread waiting on that condition gets notified. With synchronized then, if threads are waiting for different reasons, it’s a possibility a thread will receive a wake up when it can’t make progress. But that isn’t an issue here if you use conditions appropriately, which is the case in the posted code.

Comment: from the doc, thanks, last point, do you mean signal will wake the same thread:  
The lock associated with this Condition is atomically released and the current thread becomes disabled for thread scheduling purposes and lies dormant until one of four things happens:

Some other thread invokes the signal() method for this Condition and the current thread happens to be chosen as the thread to be awakened; or

Comment: cjava: not sure what you mean. signal affects only  awaiting threads.